# A Foreach loop for a join table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, foreach

I am trying to build a dynamic subnavigation with Codeigniter. I have managed successfully to build a dynamic main navigation, but can't seem to manage to loop through the data from the joined table. In my code below i know i am not using the Foreach for the submenu correctly, but can somebody please help me or at least point me in the right direction.

Thank you a lot in advance

I am loading the foreach loops in the view like so

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $page_menu = $row->page_menu;
        $page_menuName = base_url().$row->url;

        //If page_menu is in database 1, show main menu item
        if ($page_menu == '1') {
            echo anchor($page_menuName, $row->page_headline)."<br/>";

        }
    }

    if ($page_id == $webpage_id)
    {
               // I WANT THIS PART TO LOOP. THIS IS DATA FROM THE JOIN TABLE
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                     echo $subpage_id. "<--SUBID-  " .$webpage_id. "<--- webpage id-  ".$subpage_headline. "<--subheadline <br/><br/>";
               }

    }
```

This is the controller:

```
                    $this->load->module('webpages');
        $query = $this->webpages->get_where_custom('url', $first_bit); 

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data['id'] = $row->id;
            $data['headline'] = $row->headline;
            $data['url'] = $row->url;
            $data['content'] = $row->content;
            $data['page_menu'] = $row->menu;
            $data['sub_id'] = $row->sub_id;
            $data['webpage_id'] = $row->webpage_id;
            $data['sub_headline'] = $row->sub_headline;
        }
```

And this is the model:

```
function get_where_custom($col, $value) {
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->where($col, $value);
    $this->db->join('subpages', 'subpages.webpage_id = webpages.id', 'left');
    $query=$this->db->get($table);
    return $query;
}
```

My tables:

### webpages

id, 
headline, 
title, 
url, 
content,
page_menu

### subpages

sub_id, 
subpage_headline, 
subpage_title, 
subpage_url, 
subpage_content, 
webpage_id, 
sub_headnav

Comment: even that the `get_where_custom` is not customized but fixed, it would help if you layout your two tables here for us to see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I have added the tables for you to see. Hope you can figger something out or advice me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
 if ($page_id == $webpage_id)
```

is not inside your foreach loop, is one thing. I know you say "i know i am not using the Foreach for the submenu correctly" but it's really hard for us to help you if you don't fix the bits you already know about before posting. No idea if what I said above is your problem or not

Comment: +1 I agree with that comment, `it's really hard for us to help you if you don't fix the bits you already know about before posting`